# Octave make command error on linux manjaro/arch linux

Tags: linux, octave, arch

```
pkg install -forge control
sh: line 1: make: command not found

error: pkg: error running 'make' for the control package
error: called from
    configure_make at line 117 column 9
    install at line 202 column 7
    pkg at line 612 column 9
```

I am trying to install the control package for octave on linux manjaro and keep getting this error

I've tried literally dragging and dropping the control package from my downloads to octave download directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need /usr/bin/make, and it isn't installed yet.

Use:

```
$ sudo apt install make build-essential
```

(I threw in a few extras that you'll be needing soon enough.)